# Fine-tuning a pretrained Spanish RoBERTa model for a different task, sentiment analysis

Tags: python, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

I'm doing sentiment analysis of Spanish tweets.

After reviewing some of the recent literature, I've seen that there's been a most recent effort to train a RoBERTa model exclusively on Spanish text (`roberta-base-bne`). It seems to perform better than the current state-of-the-art model for Spanish language modeling so far, [BETO](https://huggingface.co/finiteautomata/beto-sentiment-analysis#beto-sentiment-analysis).

The RoBERTa model has been trained for a variety of tasks, which do not include text classification.
I want to take this [RoBERTa model](https://huggingface.co/BSC-TeMU/roberta-base-bne) and fine-tune it for text classification, more specifically, sentiment analysis.

I've done all the preprocessing and created the dataset objects, and want to natively train the model.

**Code**

```
# Training with native TensorFlow 

from transformers import TFRobertaForSequenceClassification

model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("BSC-TeMU/roberta-base-bne")

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(16), epochs=3, batch_size=16)
```

**Question**
My questions is regarding the `TFRobertaForSequenceClassification`: 
Is it correct to use this, since it's not specified in the [model card](https://huggingface.co/BSC-TeMU/roberta-base-bne)? Instead of the `AutoModelForMaskedLM`  specified in the model card.

Do we, by simply applying `TFRobertaForSequenceClassification`, imply that it will automatically apply the trained (and pretrained) knowledge to the new task, namely text classification?

Answer (score 4):

The model in the model card references what essentially the model *has been trained on*. If you are familiar with architectural choices for different modeling tasks (e.g., token classification vs sequence classification), it should become clear that these models will have *slightly* different layouts, specifically in the layers after the Transformer output layer. For token classification, this is (generally speaking) Dropout and an additional linear layer, mapping from the `hidden_size` of the model to the number of output classes. See [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py#L1652) for an example with BERT.

This means that the model checkpoint which was pre-trained with a different learning objective will **not** have weights for this final layer, but instead you train these (comparably few) parameters during your fine-tuning. In fact, for PyTorch models you will generally get a warning when loading a model checkpoint that slightly differs in the available weights:

> Some weights of the model checkpoint at `bert-base-uncased` were not used when initializing `BertForSequenceClassification`: [...]

- This IS expected if you are initializing `BertForSequenceClassification` from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a `BertForSequenceClassification` model from a `BertForPreTraining` model). [...]

This is exactly what you are doing, so as long as you have a decent number of fine-tuning examples (depending on the number of classes, I would suggest 10e3-10e4 as a rule of thumb), this will not affect your training by much.

I want to point out, however, that it might be necessary for you to specify the number of labels that your `TokenClassification` layer has. You can do this, by specifying it during the loading of your model:

```py
from transformers import TFRobertaForSequenceClassification
roberta = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("BSC-TeMU/roberta-base-bne", 
                                                             num_labels=<your_value>)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. 
I had to do some changes to the code (see above). I added the `num_labels` and `from_pt` arguments to the model variable. 

However, now, when I try to train the model, I get the following error: 

`UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
  [[node Cast (defined at <ipython-input-25-53a6872f2c55>:9) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_45018]

Function call stack:
train_function`

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have clarified that this "recipe" is specifically only related to loading the TF model. I think altering the question afterwards is also not a good idea, since it doesn't reflect the actual problem state at the time of writing my answer. Instead, I would suggest that you open a new question with the updated code, and, if possible, revert your question here to the state it was before.

Comment: Okay, understood. I just did that. 

I also managed to solve the above error by converting my labels to ints.
The model is currently training.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the problem above wasn't related to loading a TF model at all. Instead, that is something I realized afterward and added to the code so that the question would rather be understood more properly and not be confused with the TF issue. Thanks a lot anyways for the hint.